Question on proving continuity in Real analysis, using epsilon-delta definition
My lecturer did this example:
Show, using the definition, that $f : \mathbb{R → R}$ given by $f(x) = x^2$ is continuous at $a = 3.$
This was the model solution:
Let $\epsilon ∈ \mathbb{R}+.$ We first note that
$$x^2 − 9 = (x − 3)(x + 3)$$
so that
$$|x^2 − 9| = |x − 3||x + 3|.$$
Now consider $x$ such that $|x − 3| < δ$, where δ will be chosen later. Then
$$|x + 3| ≤ |x − 3| + 6 < δ + 6.$$
So, in particular, if $δ ≤ 4$ then $|x + 3| < 10$. Hence
$$|x^2 − 9| < 10δ$$
for $|x − 3| < δ$ and when $δ ≤ 4$.
Now choose $δ = \min \{\epsilon /10, 4\}$. Then it follows that $|x^2 − 9| < \epsilon$ whenever $|x − 3| < δ$. By
definition, $f$ is continuous at $a = 3$.
I don't get why we decided to choose $δ ≤ 4$ and then $δ = \min \{\epsilon /10, 4\}$. Then it follows that $|x^2 − 9| < \epsilon$ whenever $|x − 3| < δ$. By
definition, $f$ is continuous at $a = 3$.
Thank you!

Nothing special about $4$. $\delta $ less than any fixed positive number will work with a suitable modification of $\min{\epsilon /10,4}$.

Okay thank you! May I ask why we do this, sorry this may be a silly question.

You want to make $\delta (\delta +6) <\epsilon$. Instead of handling this quadratic inequality it is simpler to first get an absolute bound for $\delta +6$

Okay, thank you!

You want $\delta$ such that
$$|x-3|<\delta\implies|x-3||x+3|<\varepsilon$$
One thing you can say is
$$|x-3||x+3|<\delta|x+3|$$
And also from triangle inequality
$$|x+3|\leq |x-3|+6<\delta+6$$
so you want $\delta$ such that
$$\delta(\delta+6)<\varepsilon$$
This is a quadratic inequality, which is hard to solve. A linear inequality will be much more convenient to handle.
Here is the trick: If, somehow, $\delta\leq 4$, then we would have $\delta(\delta+6)\le 10\delta$, and then we would only worry out $10\delta\leq\varepsilon$. So, essentially we would need to ensure is that $\delta\leq 4$ AND $10\delta\leq\varepsilon$. That is easy:
$$\delta=\min\left\{\frac{\varepsilon}{10},4\right\}$$
But you notice there is nothing special about $4$, you could have said, $\delta\le 1$ and $7\delta<\varepsilon$ and chosen $\delta=\min\left\{\frac{\varepsilon}{7},1\right\}$.
You may wonder why use the inequality on $\delta+6$, but not on all of $\delta(\delta+6)$? If we did that, we would have gotten $\delta(\delta+6)<4(10)=40$ (or $1(7)=7$), which would make us helpless for any $\varepsilon<40$ (or $7$ respectively).
Why not use the inequality on $\delta$ instead of $\delta+6$? You can try thinking. I will put the solution in spoiler below.

 That would give $\delta+6\leq\frac{\varepsilon}4$. This has an issue. Remember we seek a $\delta>0$. But then whatever $\delta$ we choose, we would have
 $$6\leq\frac{\varepsilon}4$$
 or $\varepsilon>24$. Uh oh! Any choice of $\delta$ does not help us if we do it that way.

Hope this helps. :)

Oh my goodness thank you!! I really really appreciate the time you took to write this out and explain this, it is so helpful for me :) Have a nice day!
